# OpenCV error: Assertion failed (src_total() > 0) in cv:warpPerspective, file imwarp.cpp, line 6090

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I'm trying to change viewport of 2D image with this code:

```
int main() {
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("10K_F_1.jpg");

    std::vector<cv::Point3f> pointsOnPlane;

    pointsOnPlane.push_back(cv::Point3f(0-input.cols/2,0-input.rows/2,0));
    pointsOnPlane.push_back(cv::Point3f(input.cols-input.cols/2,0-input.rows/2,0));
    pointsOnPlane.push_back(cv::Point3f(input.cols-input.cols/2,input.rows-input.rows/2,0));
    pointsOnPlane.push_back(cv::Point3f(0-input.cols/2,input.rows-input.rows/2,0));

    std::vector<cv::Point2f> originalPointsInImage;
    originalPointsInImage.push_back(cv::Point2f(0,0));
    originalPointsInImage.push_back(cv::Point2f(input.cols,0));
    originalPointsInImage.push_back(cv::Point2f(input.cols,input.rows));
    originalPointsInImage.push_back(cv::Point2f(0,input.rows));

    std::cout << "original pixel positions:" << std::endl;
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<originalPointsInImage.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << originalPointsInImage[i] << std::endl;

    cv::Mat cameraIntrinsics = cv::Mat::eye(3,3,CV_64FC1);

    cameraIntrinsics.at<double>(0,0) = 500.0;
    cameraIntrinsics.at<double>(1,1) = 500.0;
    cameraIntrinsics.at<double>(0,2) = input.cols/2.0;
    cameraIntrinsics.at<double>(1,2) = input.rows/2.0;

    std::vector<double> distCoefficients;

    cv::Mat rVec;
    cv::Mat tVec;
    cv::solvePnP(pointsOnPlane, originalPointsInImage, cameraIntrinsics, distCoefficients, rVec, tVec);

    // let's increase the distance a bit
    tVec = tVec*2;
    double angle = -45; // degrees

    cv::Mat rVec2 = getRotationMatrixAroundY(angle);

    std::vector<cv::Point2f> projectedPointsOnImage;
    cv::projectPoints(pointsOnPlane, rVec2, tVec, cameraIntrinsics, distCoefficients, projectedPointsOnImage);

    cv::Mat H = cv::findHomography(originalPointsInImage, projectedPointsOnImage);

    cv::Mat warped;
    cv::warpPerspective(input, warped, H, input.size(), 1, 0);

    cv::imshow("input", input);
    cv::imshow("warped", warped);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

when I run it, I got the error:

> OpenCV error: Assertion failed (src_total() > 0) in cv:warpPerspective, file imwarp.cpp, line 6090

I try to found a solution but can't. I'm using OpenCV 3.0 on visual studio 2012.

Please help me to fix this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Was the input  image loaded? Your code does not check if the imread was a success.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. It's my bad. I do not check the imread is succes or not. after move image to the right location the above code is run. Thanks alot